# std::map clear() takes too long

Tags: c++

I'm creating a big `std::map` that contains a custom struct. This struct has many `std::vector` as its member.
It takes a long time when `clear()` the map object.

The example code I ran takes more than 80% of RAM. I suspect the swap memory is related to this issue, but even if that's the case, I'm not sure why it takes so long to delete the contents of the std::map.

Can anyone please advise what is happening?

Below is the example code, which takes roughly ~100 seconds(it varies quite much) in my machine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

struct MyStruct {
    std::vector<int64_t> vi01;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi02;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi03;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi04;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi05;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi06;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi07;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi08;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi09;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi10;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi11;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi12;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi13;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi14;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi15;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi16;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi17;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi18;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi19;
    std::vector<int64_t> vi20;

    std::vector<std::string> vs01;
    std::vector<std::string> vs02;
    std::vector<std::string> vs03;
    std::vector<std::string> vs04;
    std::vector<std::string> vs05;
    std::vector<std::string> vs06;
    std::vector<std::string> vs07;
    std::vector<std::string> vs08;
    std::vector<std::string> vs09;
    std::vector<std::string> vs10;
    std::vector<std::string> vs11;
    std::vector<std::string> vs12;
    std::vector<std::string> vs13;
    std::vector<std::string> vs14;
    std::vector<std::string> vs15;
    std::vector<std::string> vs16;
    std::vector<std::string> vs17;
    std::vector<std::string> vs18;
    std::vector<std::string> vs19;
    std::vector<std::string> vs20;
};

int main() {

    std::map<std::string, MyStruct> sId_MyStruct{};

    // roughly 500 * 7'000 * 2'000 = 7'000'000'000 bytes (7GB)
    // but std::vector's capacity() would be bigger.
    for (int64_t i=10'000ULL; i < 10'000ULL+7'000ULL ; ++i) {
        
        std::string sId = std::to_string(i);
        MyStruct & myStruct = sId_MyStruct[sId];

        for (int64_t j=10'000ULL; j<(10'000ULL+2'000ULL); ++j) {
            // Figures for simple reference only. 
            // Not considered the actual capacity of the vectors.

            // 8 bytes per element x 20 = 160 bytes.
            myStruct.vi01.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi02.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi03.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi04.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi05.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi06.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi07.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi08.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi09.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi10.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi11.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi12.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi13.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi14.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi15.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi16.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi17.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi18.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi19.push_back(j);
            myStruct.vi20.push_back(j);

            // 15 bytes(string's capacity) per element x 20 = 300bytes.
            std::string sj = std::to_string(j);
            myStruct.vs01.push_back(sj);    
            myStruct.vs02.push_back(sj);    
            myStruct.vs03.push_back(sj);    
            myStruct.vs04.push_back(sj);    
            myStruct.vs05.push_back(sj);    
            myStruct.vs06.push_back(sj);    
            myStruct.vs07.push_back(sj);    
            myStruct.vs08.push_back(sj);    
            myStruct.vs09.push_back(sj);    
            myStruct.vs10.push_back(sj);
            myStruct.vs11.push_back(sj);
            myStruct.vs12.push_back(sj);
            myStruct.vs13.push_back(sj);
            myStruct.vs14.push_back(sj);
            myStruct.vs15.push_back(sj);
            myStruct.vs16.push_back(sj);
            myStruct.vs17.push_back(sj);
            myStruct.vs18.push_back(sj);
            myStruct.vs19.push_back(sj);
            myStruct.vs20.push_back(sj);
        }

        if (i % 1'000 == 0)
            std::cout << "sId:" << sId << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "std::map object creation finished." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "press anything and enter to continue.";
    std::string sIn;
    std::cin >> sIn;
    //std::cout << sIn << '\n';

    std::cout << "std::map clear() start." << std::endl;

    auto beg = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    sId_MyStruct.clear();
    auto fin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto dur = fin - beg;
    auto sec = (dur).count() / 1'000'000'000;
    std::cout << sec << " seconds taken." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "======main fin=======" << std::endl;

}
```

(This is a follow-up question after asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77560972/10027592) since a minimal reproducible example was requested.)

Edit for future reference)

I tried additional tests with different setups after reading the comments and the answer by @Elliott.

->Conclusion:

1. It seems that the OS's memory swapping with the disk is not a direct cause of this result, since `clear()` took quite a while even when the memory(RAM) usage was not very high(even when ~40% use).
2. Performance of `std::map`'s `clear()` and `std::unordered_map`'s `clear()` is quite different, especially when using only `int64_t` as the type of the vectors' elements.
3. Changing the type of the vector's elements from `std::string` to `int64_t` increases the performance of `clear()`, as expected, though not dramatically.
4. Things to do in the future: (1) Avoid using heap allocation (2) If using heap allocation, use "flat" data structure (3) Writing a custom allocator(see @paddy's comment).

Results of additional tests:
<sub>(it varies depending on the machine, configurations, etc., but just for reference only)</sub>

- Using `std::map` (as the original post)

1. total 40 `vector<int64_t>` and no `vector<string>` decreased the time ~30%(took ~70sec).
2. total 60 `vector<int64_t>` and no `vector<string>` increased the time ~40%(took ~140sec).

- Using `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::map`

1. total 20 `vector<int64_t>` and 20 `vector<string>` (as the original post with std::map)  decreased the time ~5%(took ~96sec)
2. total 40 `vector<int64_t>` and no `vector<string>` decreased the time ~70%(took ~30sec).
3. total 60 `vector<int64_t>` and no `vector<string>` decreased the time ~40%(took ~64sec).

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Takes ~30 seconds for me. Visual Studio 2022 release build, 32gb RAM. Are you compiling with optimizations?

Comment: It might be fun to replace `std::map` with `std::unordered_map` in this example, just to see what difference it makes in the measured performance.

Comment: Regardless of which standard container you use, if allocation is the bottleneck then consider writing your own custom allocator. For special use cases, an arena allocation scheme can help by dishing out bits of larger chunks of memory while not care about ever re-using that memory. So you can make the deallocation step a no-op, and then after _completely_ freeing all memory (noting that the `clear` method does not always guarantee that) you can tell the allocator to discard its memory blocks.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for testing the code. Yes, I think I'm using enough optimization in VS2022(max optimization favor speed `\O2`).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks. Following your comment, I tried testing with `std::unordered_map` and it showed better performance especially when the struct contains only `vector<int64_t>` without any `vector<string>`. Added the results in the post.

Comment: @paddy Wow, thanks, I'm still learning C++, so I'll give it a try when I become more proficient :) If you have any documents that may be helpful to implement what you described, please leave a comment. Thank you.

Comment: There is also `flat_map` that is popular for a reason, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html

Comment: Depending on your usage pattern, you might find better performance with a sorted `std::vector` using `std::lower_bound` for lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `std::vector`, `std::map` has a tree structure with nodes that are individually allocated. When `std::map`'s destructor is called it has to iteratively go through each of those elements and free the memory for each node - and when each node is freed it has to free the `std::string` in the key, and all those `std::vector` members in the value (in `MyStruct`), many of them also having `std::string` as elements which then each need to be freed!!
You're computer's probably being overwhelmed by cache misses, as memory allocated like this are typically at completely different addresses in the physical memory.

So when you've got such a large map I'd expect it to take a long time, although it'll vary a lot depending on the machine, OS, compiler - and make sure to compile in optimised.

Overall, though, if you want good data structures for speed, try to avoid heap allocations for small data structs where possible/practical, and if you do use heap allocations, try to use flat data structures than have just a single heap allocation - often you can get the same or better time/space complexity for your specific problem (with a bit of creativity and logic - sometimes rethinking how or when you access the data). Otherwise, if you need a tree structure, try not to have so many nested heap allocations like this one. It's too much!

Comment: Thank you. Could you give some simple examples for avoiding heap allocations? Some sources/documentation would be great as well. Also, what are examples of "flat data structure"? Are `std::vector` and `std::array` flat data structures, since they are not "tree" structures like `std::map`?

Comment: Also, after reading your answer, I tested without the `vector<std::string>`, only with `vector<int64_t>`. Indeed std::map `clear()` took less time, although not a huge difference considering the difference between `int64_t` and `std::string`(It might become faster if the std::map's key is also a primitive type, I guess). I added the test results in the post just for simple reference. Thanks.

Comment: @starriet, I should clarify that by "flat data structure" I mean contiguous in the physical memory. But, more than this, you want data that's typically used together to be close together (its address in physical memory to differ by as fewer indices as possible). This is called Data Oriented Programming, where you try to minimise cache misses. We're now straying from your original question, but `std::array` is perfectly contiguous in memory, while `std::vector` is actually composed of two contiguous sections: one which stores its members, and the other that sores all the elements of the vector.

Comment: @starriet, because it's only composed of only two sections, `std::vector` is loosely called flat/contiguous. `std::set` and `std::map` are usually implemented as Red-Black trees that have separate memory allocations for each node. It should be noted that some tree structures are implemented using contiguous memory. It's common to use `std:make_heap` on an `std::vector`. Relating this back to your original question; if elements are a plain-old-data type, like `int`, then `std::vector` can be destructed in constant time, but `std::map` requires linear time. Nesting these multiplies the problem.